# React Native - Tappable Numbers vs. Tappable Letters Issue

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a tappable "link" at the end of a block of text (it has to be a tappable region on the same line, and alway suffix the text). I thought this would be easy, as it's just text nestled in with text..The tappable region should be a reference number, for depicted as [number], for example [1] or [2]

I observed that when I create an onpress like this

```
 <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
             {this.itemSentences()}
             <Text style={{color: 'red'}} onPress={this.sourceNumberPressed.bind(this)}>[1] </Text>
           </Text>
```

it does not work (cannot tap on it, or it's really hard to tap on it because the symbols [1] are too narrow to tap on). Even increasing the font size doesn't seem to help at all.

Whereas if I change to this:

```
<Text style={styles.textStyle}>
             {this.itemSentences()}
             <Text style={{color: 'red'}} onPress={this.sourceNumberPressed.bind(this)}Tap here! </Text>
           </Text>
```

It's extremely easy to tap on, and it works. It's almost as if the letters work but numbers do not. If I do a combination of "test1" the 'test' part of the string is easy to tap, but the '1' is not.

Any ideas why this is the case? Does react have a bug where small numbers won't tap, or is the "hitbox" just too small?

Any ideas what I can do here to make it so strings like [1] and [2] are easily tappable?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Rather use Touchables / Pressables for that purpose, with `hitSlop`: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#hitslop

Comment: but can that fit into a <text> element? Wouldn't it be considered nesting a view which will throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer out of this. So you can use Touchables / Pressables for the actual `onPress` event together with `hitSlop`. See example in here: https://snack.expo.dev/@zvona/hitslop

Code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
    {'Some Example Text'}
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={popAlert}
      hitSlop={{ top: 6, right: 6, bottom: 6, left: 6 }}
    >
      <Text style={styles.reference}>{'[1]'}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </Text>
</View>
```